# Sharepoint Wiki Recent Changes : Update number of entries shown

Tags: sharepoint, wiki

By default, only 5 recent wiki page entries are displayed in the left navigation. Also rejected wikis are also shown.

I need to increase it to 10 and also want to show only approved wiki pages only.